# Do different monsters in Nephalem Rifts grant more progress towards completion?

Tags: diablo-iii

While in a Nephalem Rift, you have a progress bar which shows your completed percentage of the rift - when the bar fills to 100%, a Rift Guardian will spawn. Occasionally when I kill a monster, the percentage of my bar does not increase.

Because of this, I'm led to believe that some monsters grant a larger amount of progress towards the completion of the Rift than others.

Is there any documentation or are there any statistics which show the specific percentage gains each monster gives in a Rift? Also, do I receive any bonus gains in percentage for massacre (or other types) bonuses?

Comment: One reason you don't see the progress bar increase on some kills is because the percentage granted is less than 1% per kill. Best way to test this is to try and keep track of exactly how many monsters you killed to make the rift guardian appear, and see if that number changes between runs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some testing on this, and I'm convinced that the wiki is currently incorrect [here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem_Rift) (it says 999 monster kills).

In my experience (in Normal) counting monsters, it took ~ 5 white monster kills to reach an  additional percentage. I also tried counting in Torment, and it seemed to be the same.

I did some additional data gathering counting the kills to reach 10% progress. It was difficult to get groups that were easy to count, and I avoided recording data for groups with the Illusionist affix, as well as enemies that continually spawn other enemies. If I was unsure in my counting, I would throw out the group of 10%, and kill whites until I reached the next 10%. Still, it is very difficult to count exactly how many enemies you are killing. This meant that I only got 2-3 data points per run. Here's my data:

1. 36 white 7 elite
2. 32 white 9 elite
3. 41 white 3 elite
4. 38 white 4 elite
5. 34 white 8 elite
6. 37 white 7 elite
7. 36 white 8 elite
8. 52 white
9. 44 white 3 elite
10. 35 white 7 elite

While this isn't a lot of data (and I didn't distinguish between Champions, Minions or Rares), we can make a couple of conclusions.

1. Elites do count as more than one kill. Using 52 kills (per 10%) as a baseline, an Elite on average gives 2.58 kills.
2. It takes ~50 kills per 10%. This would put the total monsters slain to complete a rift at 500.
3. Counting monsters as you go is not a fun or efficient way to run a rift :-)

Comment: Awesome - this is just what I was looking for. Do you know if there is any additional information regarding the amount of kills an elite or champion will give?

Comment: Hey John, I've gone through and tested this a bit. I'm sorry to have given you faulty information before. I added some science to this edition of the answer, so it should be much better

Comment: Have you considered that it might be total HP of monsters slain? I seem to progress faster in a group of people even when we don't kill many monsters.

Comment: Maybe it's based on base exp value of the monster?  If you kill "trash minions" (like the really weak shadow fiend or frail skeletons - the stuff that gives below-average exp), does it move the bar less than killing a standard white mob?

Comment: These are both good suggestions, but during my testing I noticed no difference between Normal and Torment 1. I can do some more testing in Torment to see if they still match. Of course, just because they match doesn't completely discount your theories, but I don't think I'm likely to attempt to keep track of experience or HP of the monsters.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! This is an excellent amount of data and I'm very appreciative of you doing it (even though it might not seem like a lot). Now we can change the 999 to 500 and have something to back it up with!

Answer (score 4):

I also did some testing and it seemed to vary, with each mob giving between .25% - .36% completion. I only tested this in one rift, recorded it and rewatched. And I agree it wasn't fun lol. Needless to say my rift didn't take 500 monster kills to complete; it varies based on rift. The one I needed required about 350.

It's hard to say whether or not some types monsters might count more or less than others (IE think swarm monsters, or big single monsters like trees, etc), but as far as I've seen completion is based purely on the number killed.

I tested for HP as well and it seems quite obvious that HP is not a factor. Killing 1 elite pack of 3 mobs on T1 had 99m HP and only yielded ~1% completion. meanwhile killing other trash mobs and looking at the HP numbers yielded 32m HP/dmg dealt for 1%, 15.3m/1%, 18.2m/1%, and 56m/1%. So there doesn't seem to be any correlation. For that last one (56m HP/dmg dealth for 1% completion), I hunted out high HP mobs specifically.

TLDR; leave high HP stragglers. For efficiency kill easy monsters in relatively high volume.